# ValueError: No objects to concatenate

Tags: python, pandas

I m trying to merge different txt. I want to create different Dataset for every different target.

```
path1 = r'C:\Users\chiar\Desktop\Dataset\A' # use your path
all_files1 = glob.glob(path1 + "/*.csv")
name= ['quat_1', 'quat_2', 'quat_3', 'quat_4']
a = pd.concat((pd.read_csv(f, names=name) for f in all_files), ignore_index=True)
a['activity'] = 'A'

path2 = r'C:\Users\chiar\Desktop\TESI\Dataset\B' # use your path
all_files2 = glob.glob(path2 + "/*.csv")
name= ['quat_1', 'quat_2', 'quat_3', 'quat_4']
b = pd.concat((pd.read_csv(f, names=name) for f in all_files2), ignore_index=True)
b['activity'] = 'B'

path3 = r'C:\Users\chiar\Desktop\TESI\Dataset\C' # use your path
all_files3 = glob.glob(path3 + "/*.csv")
name= ['quat_1', 'quat_2', 'quat_3', 'quat_4']
c = pd.concat((pd.read_csv(f, names=name) for f in all_files3), ignore_index=True)
c['activity'] = 'C'
```

And it works for the first 5 lines, it creates a DataFrame called A with the right values and labels, but then for the second and the third Dataframe (b and c) I obtain this error:

> *ValueError: No objects to concatenate*

Someone can help me here? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you are iterating over `all_files` (unknown) and not `all_files1`. So that might explain why the first 5 lines work.

Then, you are on a Windows filesystem, so the hierarchy delimiter is `\` and not `/`, you should use `os.path.join` instead (so you don't have to worry about the user's filesystem):

```
import os
all_files1 = glob.glob(os.path.join(path1, "*.csv"))
```

Comment: Are you sure there is a csv file in the said folder ?
Can you print `all_files1` ?

Comment: Or that the path actually exists ?

Comment: I take it that at least one of this questions related to the deleted previous comments is answered by "no" :-D